# CSV data imports into SQL are showing the data in the wrong order

Tags: sql, excel, csv, import

I am currently developing a backend database system on an online university server for sql/phpmadmin.

I am looking to store data across various tables so that a customer:

1. Can search to see flights that are available and a flight dispatch officer
2. Will be able to view the data from the tables and assign crew to certain flights across certain days.

I have been using csv files to upload the data from excel on where the rows are columns are titled on the phpmyadmin but not on the excel files.

The files all upload correctly, except for ONE flaw-I have the flight codes ordered sequentially but when I upload these or certain other files, it uploads them in the wrong order. I want 1-18 sequentially; instead it is 1, 10, 11 and then 2-9 etc.

When uploading I have selected csv type and have been told to leave the "columns enclosed with" field empty and to tick the box that says "replace existing data."

Does anyone know how to fix this? I don't want it to affect how I perform the queries for this database.

I can include the table output if requested. If I click edit after upload, the code shows the correct order as below:

```
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('1', 'FWL-101', 'BFS', 'LGW', '600', '710')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('2', 'FWL-102', 'LGW', 'BFS', '700', '810')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('3', 'FWL-103', 'BFS', 'LGW', '800', '910')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('4', 'FWL-104', 'LGW', 'BFS', '900', '1010')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('5', 'FWL-105', 'BFS', 'LGW', '1000', '1110')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('6', 'FWL-106', 'LGW', 'BFS', '1100', '1210')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('7', 'FWL-107', 'BFS', 'BRU', '700', '915')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('8', 'FWL-108', 'BRU', 'BFS', '800', '1015')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('9', 'FWL-109', 'BFS', 'HAM', '600', '840')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('10', 'FWL-110', 'HAM', 'BFS', '700', '940')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('11', 'FWL-111', 'BFS', 'GNB', '1000', '1215')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('12', 'FWL-112', 'GNB', 'BFS', '1100', '1415')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('13', 'FWL-113', 'LGW', 'BRU', '700', '905')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('14', 'FWL-114', 'BRU', 'LGW', '800', '1005')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('15', 'FWL-115', 'LGW', 'HAM', '600', '850')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('16', 'FWL-116', 'HAM', 'LGW', '700', '950')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('17', 'FWL-117', 'LGW', 'GRB', '1000', '1200')# 1 row affected.
REPLACE INTO `routes` VALUES ('18', 'FWL-118', 'GRB', 'LGW', '1100', '1400')# 1 row affected.
```

However, when I have refreshed the database after uploading the csv file, it shows like this:

The fight codes are beginning with FWL and should display in ascending numerial order, along with the times shown next to them. This is the incorrect order below:

```
Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
1
FWL-101
BFS
LGW
600
710

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
10
FWL-110
HAM
BFS
700
940

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
11
FWL-111
BFS
GNB
1000
1215

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
12
FWL-112
GNB
BFS
1100
1415

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
13
FWL-113
LGW
BRU
700
905

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
14
FWL-114
BRU
LGW
800
1005

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
15
FWL-115
LGW
HAM
600
850

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
16
FWL-116
HAM
LGW
700
950

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
17
FWL-117
LGW
GRB
1000
1200

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
18
FWL-118
GRB
LGW
1100
1400

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
2
FWL-102
LGW
BFS
700
810

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
3
FWL-103
BFS
LGW
800
910

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
4
FWL-104
LGW
BFS
900
1010

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
5
FWL-105
BFS
LGW
1000
1110

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
6
FWL-106
LGW
BFS
1100
1210

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
7
FWL-107
BFS
BRU
700
915

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
8
FWL-108
BRU
BFS
800
1015

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
9
FWL-109
BFS
HAM
600
840
```

Comment: I suggest you add some code.  It is not at all clear to me how you are generating the CSV files.

Comment: It sounds like you're sorting them as strings instead of numbers.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the edits as it won't let me add jpeg images.

Comment: I am sorting them as varchar, it gives a syntax error if I try anything else. the route id is also varchar, it is 1, 2 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ORDER BY` on varchar fields makes the value "12" show up *before* the value "2" - this is correct if sorting strings. In your database, or at least in your order by, you should do something like this:

```
ORDER BY cast(<my_varchar_field_of_numeric_values> as int)
```

You also need to make sure that any non-numeric values that might show up in that column (it *is* a varchar field, so you never know) are handled correctly.

Comment: I will also have a column with passport numbers and the booking references, both of which are varchar. However, I have changed the route id to an int and now it outputs in the same order. a different table I have is reservation which will have booking ref as varchar, passport no as varchar, route id as int and date as text. booking ref is the primary key. would I need to have route id as the first column to prevent this from going in a strange order?

Comment: No. If you want to order by rows with the same booking_ref *first*, then by passport_no, then by route_id, then specify them in that order. Character fields get sorted as character strings, numbers get sorted as numbers. Always.

Comment: thanks for your help, I will try those tables now and hopefully there will be no further problems. Would I need to bookmark the tables? It seems to save it even I don't. I have bookmarked the tables and will bookmark the queries, is it needed/good practice to bookmark the imports as well, even if there are already saved?